# How to save data to Firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the code am using already but its not saving my data in Firestore. Please help

```
Future<void>saveRestaurantDataToDb({String url, String restaurantName, String mobileNumber, String dialog}){
    User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    DocumentReference _restaurants = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('restaurants').doc(user.uid);
    _restaurants.set({
      'uid':user.uid,
      'restaurantName': restaurantName,
      'mobile': mobileNumber,
      'email': this.email,
      'dialog': dialog,
      'address': '${this.placeName}:${this.restaurantAddress}',
      'location': GeoPoint(this.restaurantLatitude, this.restaurantLongitude),
      'restaurantOpen': true, // will use latter
      'rating': 0.00, //later
      'totalRating': 0, //later
      'isTopPicked': true, //later
      'imageUrl': url,
    });
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Complementing the answer of  user15220005 I suggest you read the documentation [1] in the section Collections & Documents# you will fine an example:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/ [1]
And also if you had a the log error It will be good to know

Answer (score 1):

try CollectionReference instead of Documentreference

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> addUser() {
  return users
    .doc('ABC123')
    .set({
      'full_name': "Mary Jane",
      'age': 18
    })
    .then((value) => print("User Added"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentReference _restaurants = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('restaurants').doc(user.uid); //add await here
```

and async to your function

Answer (score 0):

```
 void postingdata() async {
    DocumentReference reference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CartHistory').doc('${widget.name}');
    await reference.set({
      "total count": widget.total_Count,
      "Name ": widget.name,
      "total sum": widget.previciousSum
    });
    return null;
  }
```